# Recyclerview does not refresh

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I try to populate an array with data from a room database.
The data is only populated in the recyclerview after I refresh the
fragment. Once refreshed, everything is displayed. Anyone  know why?

So the weird thing is that everything works fine but only once the fragment is refreshed.

I already implemented the notifydataset changed function but without success.

```
class WorkoutFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentWorkoutBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentWorkoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
        val sharedPreference =  activity?.getSharedPreferences("WORKOUT_BUTTON", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val sharedPreference2 =  activity?.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor = sharedPreference?.edit()
        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerview
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        var workout: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var workoutid: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
        workout.clear()
        workoutid.clear()
        val adapter = AdapterWorkoutsHeader(workoutid as ArrayList<Int>,
            workout as ArrayList<String>
        )
        recyclerView?.adapter = adapter


        val user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
        val parkname = user.get("parkname")
        val currentSpot: TextView = binding.currentSpot
        currentSpot.text = parkname.toString()
        val openNav: ImageButton = binding.openNav
        openNav.setOnClickListener {
            val mDrawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = activity?.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
            mDrawerLayout!!.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
        
        val addWorkout: Button = binding.button
        addWorkout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), ChooseWorkoutActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        Thread{
            val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                requireContext(),
                AppDatabase::class.java, "workout.db"
            ).build()
            val userDao = db.todoDao()


            for (i in 0 until userDao.getWorkoutSize()){
                userDao.getChosenWorkout(i)[0].workout?.let { workout.add(it) }
                userDao.getChosenWorkout(i)[0].workoutid?.let { workoutid.add(it) }

                activity?.runOnUiThread {
                    val adapter = AdapterWorkoutsHeader(workoutid as ArrayList<Int>,
                        workout as ArrayList<String>
                    )
                    recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

            }


            //var parkNames2 = parkNames.toTypedArray()
            //recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()




        }.start()

        

        return root
    }

    
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use functions to separate your concerns, it's impossible to read your code.
The rule is that each function or method should do one thing.
You will have hundreds of errors because you can't read your own code efficiently.

Comment: Why are you building your database in your fragment. You should only be observing the livedata in your fragment. If the data has changed then update your recycler adapter.

Comment: this not a solution but you should remove `recyclerView?.adapter = adapter` from inside the thread, call it outside with assigning a data array to it,  you should initialize the adapter to the recyclerView outside the thread and keep its reference or a reference to the data array, when some new item comes in, add it to the data array and call `adapter.notifyItemInserted(positionOfInsertedItem)` with its position rather than calling notifyDataSetChanged for every single item.

Comment: Thanks Emanuel, will try to make it more readable. I do not get any errors though. 
Thanks Omar, will try it out.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I am using live data now and observe it in a Fragment. I get the same error though --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69610704/room-live-data-in-fragment-updates-only-on-fragment-refresh

Answer (score 0):

1. Data updating should be done from the UI thread

   ```
   runOnUiThread { 
      recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
   ```
2. Synchronization problem

   ```
   var workout: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
   var workoutid: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
   ```

   is on UI thread, but modified from the other thread, so synchronization or synchronized collections `Collections.synchronizedList` can be used

Comment: thanks but it did not work. It is also already on the main thread due to "activity?.runOnUiThread" right?

Comment: please try updated answer

Comment: no does not work either. Thanks anyway